# Changing the cursor in asp.net using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm trying to change the cursor to an hourglass in my asp.net application.

1. Add this javascript

   ```
   funcion hourglass() {
       document.body.style.cursor = "wait";   
   }
   ```
2. Then in my code in the page load event:

   ```
   button.Attributes.Add("onclick","hourglass()")
   ```

when I click the button, the cursor changes but the system freezes and does not reload the page!

Any tips?

Comment: Please post more code and/or clarify your intent.  Are you trying to make it so that when the user clicks a button, it changes the cursor to an hourglass while waiting for the next page to load?  Are you sure this is a desirable user experience?  More common would be to show a modal with a spinner and a loading message.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `OnClientClick`

```
button.OnClientClick = "hourglass(); return true;";
```

Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use button like this

```
<asp:Button ID="btn" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Text="Button Text" OnClick="btnRefresh_Click" CssClass="btn"   OnClientClick="hourglass(); return true;"/>
```

While going to server side it will change your cursor and code behind function will execute